# Float point placement with anti aliasing

Tags: image-processing, interpolation, antialiasing

I have an image of size `H`,`W`, and I would like to draw a point on this image at `x`,`y`, where those values are floats.
I tried bi-linear interpretation but that didn't give good results, but when I generated hi res image (e.g. of size `4H`,`4W`, and placed the point at `4x`,`4y`), and then downsampled it with AA filter (or just xv
area), I got a much better quality.
Is there's a way to get the same results without generating the hi res image?